# connecting to NAS (again...) mount at boot

Tags: mount, storage

Linux is driving me nuts again...
I have already one EOS6 with NAS mounting at boot, no problem at all.

Now I am doing another EOS6 install (same PC, same NAS, another SSD).

Copied everything as per original installation

(same /etc/fstab line, same mount point, same username, same password, etc)

and still get this crappy message:

[image]

Anybody got any ideas, please (before I shoot myself...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic over...

I forgot that it needs cifs-utils installed before it will work.

Why is it not included?

Mounting any external stuff is real PITA.

Elementary is so good at making things simple for new users, that I wonder why this area is so neglected?